# How to get the sum of a DataFrame in Pandas using pivot_table function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

test.py:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Horticulture\\test_data.xlsx")
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index=["sizeoforchardholding", "nooforchardists"],
    columns="fruit_plant_kind",
    values=["sizeoforchardholding", "nooforchardists"],
    aggfunc={"fruit_plant_count": sum},
    fill_value=0,
    margins=True,
).reset_index()
print(df_pivot)
result_pivot = df_pivot.to_dict("r")
print(result_pivot)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Code\pandas test\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 95, in 
pivot_table
    table = __internal_pivot_table(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 228, in __internal_pivot_table
    table = _add_margins(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 272, in _add_margins
    grand_margin = _compute_grand_margin(data, values, aggfunc, margins_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 342, in _compute_grand_margin
    if isinstance(aggfunc[k], str):
KeyError: 'sizeoforchardholding'
```

this is the sample output of the data in the`xlsx` file:

```
print (df)
  fruit_plant_kind sizeoforchardholding  nooforchardists  fruit_plant_count
1            Apple      0.5 to 1.0 Acre                2                  6
2           Almond      0.5 to 1.0 Acre                2                500
3           Almond      1.0 to 1.5 Acre                1                300
4            Aonla      1.0 to 1.5 Acre                1                250
```

So what I want the output to be is to index the data according to the   `sizeoforchardholding` and `nooforchardists` and the column to be the `fruit_plant_kind` and the value should be the sum of `fruit_plant_kind` according to these two indexes

eg:

```
                 sizeoforchardholding nooforchardists fruit_plant_count
fruit_plant_kind                                                 Almond Aonla  Apple Apple seedling Pear Plum Star fruit    
0                     0.5 to 1.0 Acre               1                 0     0    800              0    0  400          0    
1                     0.5 to 1.0 Acre               2               506     0    550              0    0    0          0    
2                     0.5 to 1.0 Acre               3                 0     0    235              0    0    0          0
```

As you can see above in `0.5 to 1.0 Acre` with `nooforchardists=2` the `Almonds = 506` is clearly the sum of the base table.

but now what I want is to get the sum of all the columns at the end. for example the sum of `Apples=1585` according to the data above.

Comment: Are you sure parameter `index` and `values` are same? `["sizeoforchardholding", "nooforchardists"]`. Can you add some data sample to question?

Comment: You can see the data sample above @jezrael

Comment: hmmm, do you need `df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
                    df,
                    index="sizeoforchardholding",
                    columns="fruit_plant_kind",
                    values="nooforchardists",
                    aggfunc='sum', margins=True, margins_name='Sum',
                    fill_value=0)` ?

Comment: No, I don't want `index` to be only `"sizeoforchardholding"`, I want it to be indexed by two columns of the `df`. and value to be according to these two indexes but the sum of `"fruit_plant_count"`

Comment: I cannot find any sample data in question and no expected ouput, so no possible get solution. Check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) part `The Ugly:`.

Comment: provided the data as you suggested

Comment: I add solution, but expected ouput not matched sample data in question, so cannot test it. If need something else can you change ouoput data by input data from question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fruit_plant_count` for parameter `values` instead `["sizeoforchardholding", "nooforchardists"]`:

```
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df,                    
                          index=["sizeoforchardholding","nooforchardists"],
                          columns="fruit_plant_kind",                     
                          values="fruit_plant_count",                     
                          aggfunc='sum', 
                          margins=True, 
                          margins_name='Sum',                     
                          fill_value=0).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df_pivot)
  sizeoforchardholding nooforchardists  Almond  Aonla  Apple   Sum
0      0.5 to 1.0 Acre               2     500      0      6   506
1      1.0 to 1.5 Acre               1     300    250      0   550
2                  Sum                     800    250      6  1056
```